# Something unidentifiable grew up in my garden

Tags: identification, algae

In one of the empty plantations from my garden something weird grew up.

Can you help identify it?
I know I need to remove it soon, but it grew up so big and wide, so I got intrigued.

Album is here:
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/w41w6yi7vfxr9tm/AACY8MGqbvxnwARdF_6_5Lx7a?dl=0
(huge pictures, couldn't upload it anywhere else)

edit:
Here's some:
[image: 1]
[image: 2]

Comment: use a photo editor to reduce the resolution and inline the images.  Asking people to go to 3rd party sites is an invitation to get viruses.

Comment: its a dropbox. I'll put the first image outside

Comment: What is the scale? It looks like microscopic imaging.

Comment: 2-5mm per bubble.

Comment: I guess that means only the microscopists amongst us will be able to answer your question.

Comment: @Graham Chiu, I think it *is* a virus.

Comment: can this growth only be seen at a microscopic level?  If its visible with the eye, then we need pictures showing that too

Comment: Hmm - "so big and wide" and 5mm macro/micro photos - do the ends of the boards on this bridge look like they were gnawed with teeth rather than sawn?

Comment: I have seed similar things in aquariums, an oxygen bubble trapped in a film of algae.

Comment: How do you know you need to remove it? How did you know it was there? You seem to be implying that it was visible without a microscope. Elaborating could help. I personally don't see this question as off-topic, no matter how much a microscope is needed to see evidence of this, but you may be waiting a while for an answer (and you should elaborate). The more people ask questions about microscopic stuff, the faster we'll be able to recruit people who can answer them. "If you build it, they will come." so the quote says. But, if we instead drive away such questions, we may not interest them so.

Comment: Anyway, clarification is needed. If you edit your question and explain how you found this, what it's growing on, and why you think you should remove it, as well as how you want to go about doing so, that could help. If there's a picture of the evidence of this that isn't microscopic, that should help.